# School system in Germany?

Tags: germany, language-test

I was wondering if anyone can explain me the school system in Germany.
I very recently got my daughter enrolled at a local school and got then got her health check up done at the public health department "einschulungsuntersuchung".

Now the doctor over there says my child is not yet ready or maybe she can get ready in 3-4 months, but as of now not yet ready. She will be starting school in August next year (turns 6 then). The doctor says her language skills are not strong enough. The girl only understands English and also at some point she is not able to comprehend what needs to be done.
I told the doctor she has never had any such problems before and also she has been to English school in India and understands English pretty well. I said you can do it again and I can help a bit.
But then the doctor said I am not saying she will not be able to go to school. The girl can if she improves in the next 3-4 months.

But can the school deny admission to my child based on her report?

Comment: Have a look at this question, which should give you some information since your situation is similar. https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/19641/school-options-for-a-non-german

Comment: I dont think the situation is similar. My daughter is in an international preschool and will turn 6 years and must attend school next summer. The.doctor said if she improves in the next 3 months she might go but I would suggest her staying one year in Kindergarten as she doesnt understand english well...but my point is my daughter understands english really well. Can I be denied admission based on her diagnosis?

Comment: There is a portion about language learning classes. That is what you must ask about in your local area.

Comment: Yes. I want my daughter to attend international school and there the knowledge of german is not necessary.

Comment: @Anony How will your daughter be able to function in a foreign county without a working knowledge of the local language?  Or do you plan to move away soon?

Comment: @Matthew Barclay we plan to move in 2-3 years and also I am fine with my daughter learning the language at her own pace but I am not okay with wasting one full year. She is a bright child and not letting her go to school is a bit too much. But my question is how much importance does the doctors opinion matters if the parents want to send the child to school.  Like the doctor said she can go to an international school next year only if she gets well adjusted and improved. But my question is will a second einschulungsuntersuchung will take place or what will theydotoknow my child has improved.

Comment: I have never heard about a doctors opinion matter in this type of case, unless of course there are other medical challenges that is not clear from the question a doctors opinion on the language skill have never mattered for us, our daughter attended school in Switzerland and Sweden and learned both German and Swedish as part of this as her native language was English

Comment: Any update on this? Did OP got it resolved?

Answer (score 1):

There are **16 school systems**, the number of federal states (*Bundesland*, pl. *Bundesländer*).
Each state has a Department of Education, traditionally called *Kultusministerium* but subsequently rebranded as *Bildungsministerium*.

I just went to [Lower Saxony’s Department of Education](https://www.mk.niedersachsen.de/) website.
Since there is no “switch to English version” button, I entered “English” as a search term.
They have a [concise guide on their school system](https://www.mk.niedersachsen.de/download/112666)
([other documents](https://www.mk.niedersachsen.de/startseite/service/publikationen/mehrsprachige_publikationen/mehrsprachige-publikationen-146861.html)).
Possibly other states have similar materials, but probably states having a large influx of migrants.

Summary (for Lower Saxony):
There is a mandatory German proficiency assessment.
If your daughter fails it, she is *sentenced* to attend a mandatory German class for *one year* before going to school.
And then she might be *asked* (but not sentenced) to attend remedial German classes.

The crucial circumstance:
The law does not differentiate whether the student will eventually attend a bilingual school or a school that has English as its main instruction language.
These are *universal* requirements.
It is called [*Schulreife*](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schulreife) (readiness for school).